# How to tag a compilation album contains multiple artists on each track?

Tags: files, music, rename

I have a huge music collection. Currently my music is like this:

```
Music
├── Album 1
│   ├── Track 1 (Artist 1 , Artist 2)
│   ├── Track 2 (Artist 2, )
│   ├── Track 3 (Artist 3 , Artist 2, Artist 4)
│   ├── Track 4 (Artist 4 , Artist 4)
│   └── Track 5 (Artist 5 , Artist 6)
├── Album 2
│   ├── Track 3 (Artist 2 , Artist 4)
│   ├── Track 4 (Artist 7 , Artist 5)
│   └── Track 5 (Artist 8 , Artist 6)
├── Album 3
│   └── Track 1 (Artist 1 , Artist 2)
├── Album 4
│   └── Track 2 (Artist 3 , Artist 1)
└── Album 5
    └── Track 3 (Artist 1 , Artist 7)
```

What is the best way to tag these music files for better usability on Banshee/Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your music player.

Have a look at [gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org/): *"An open-source jukebox for large collections of mp3/ogg/flac/mpc/ape files, written in perl"*, available in the Software Center.

gmusicbrowser allows you to tag each track with multiple entries for artist and genre (and more). That means that you can tag Track 1 with `Artist 1; Artist 2` under *Track Artist*, and when you browse your artists only two entries, *Artist 1* and *Artist 2* will show -- not *Artist 1; Artist 2*.